# Provide a proof or counterexample for the following statement: If $a, b$, and $c$ are nonzero integers and $a|bc$ $\rightarrow a|b$ or $a|c.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Provide a proof or counterexample for the following statement: If $a, b$, and $c$ are nonzero integers and $a|bc$ $\rightarrow a|b$ or $a|c.$

I started off by solving for $a|b$ and $a|c$, but then got confused on how to deal with $a|bc$. Any helps or tips will be appreciated.

Comment: ``Provide a proof **and** counterexample  for the following statement''??

Comment: Hint: $bc \mid bc$

Comment: Simplest counterexample is probably $a = 4$, $b = c = 2$,

Answer (score 2):

$a=8$, $b=4$, $c=6$ (so $bc=24$) is a counterexample; $8$ divides $24$ but not $4$ or $6$.